# quartz scheduler jobs empty in new thread .net

Tags: .net, quartz.net

I'm using the .net version of quartz.  When I add jobs to the scheduler in thread 1 the jobs don't exist in thread 2.  I wrapped the scheduler in a singleton and looking at the HashCode it should be the same instance of the scheduler.  This seem to only happen in IIS. Any idea of why it might be doing this?